# A bash script to unrar all files in a sub directory in linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unrar

I'm on Ubuntu server 18.04.

My main goal is to run a script from a parent directory which **unrars all the files inside all sub directories of the parent directory**.
I have also installed `apt install unrar` and it is located at "/usr/bin/unrar".
This is what I have come up with till now. But it does not seem to work:

```
for dir in 'pwd/*/'
do
  dir=${dir%*/} 
  cd dir
    for file in dir/*/
  do
    "/usr/bin/unrar" x dir/*.r* dir/
done
```

I've found a working script for Windows which uses 7zip [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/8092/how-do-i-extract-all-archives-in-the-subdirectories-of-this-folder)

Comment: The immediate problem is that the single quotes prevent the wildcard from matching any files. If `pwd` is not the literal name of the only directory wou want to traverse, you should probably replace it simply with `.` (the proper way to needlessly call the `pwd` command would be `"$(pwd)"`).

Comment: Similarly, if you want to use the variable `dir` rather than try to access a directory named literally `dir`, the syntax for that is `"$dir"`. (The quotes are not syntactically required, but always a good idea when manipulating references to unknown file names; of course `/usr/bin/unrar` is a literal reference to a file with no funny surprises like `?` or `*` in its name, so quoting that is superfluous and slightly odd. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable))

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting example; adjust pattern and echo statements as needed:

```
#!/bin/bash

pattern='*/*.rar'
archives=($pattern)

if [[ "${archives[@]}" == "$pattern" ]]; then
    echo NONE 1>&2
    exit
fi

for rpath in "${archives[@]}"; do
    dir=${rpath%/*}
    rar=${rpath##*/}
    pushd "$dir" > /dev/null
    echo -e "\ndir: $dir"
    echo unrar args "$rar"
    popd > /dev/null
done
```

Comment: Putting the pattern in a variable and then immediately using it just once to populate an array seems like a weird way to waste typing and a tiny amount of memory.

Comment: The var pattern is present for OP ease-of-use and there are multiple uses, lines 4 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to unrar every rar file in the directory where it was found, `find` can do that directly. It takes some getting used to, but it's well worth learning.

```sh
find . -name '*.rar' -execdir unrar {} \;
```

Briefly, `-execdir` says to run the stuff up to `\;` on each found file in the directory where it was found; the `{}` placeholder gets replaced with the file name.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name '*.rar' -execdir unrar {} \;
```

This didn't work for me.

I changed it to this and it worked.

```
find . -name '*.rar' -execdir unrar e -r {} \;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).